# Different font size when item from combo box is selected in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, text, fonts, combobox

In my combo box I have 8,9,10 and 11 item
so I want to set a different font size when 8 9 10 or 11 is selected
now can anyone guide me how do I set different font size when item from combo box is selected

Comment: And you want to set the font size of what? All elements of the whole application, of the combobox or any other control?

Comment: actually i am making word processor in which i have taken a richtextbox and a combo box. in combo box i have given the font size 8 9 10 and 11. i just want when 8 is call from the combo box it change the size of the font. and how i can put a specific size in 8, 9, 10 and 11

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can register a `SelectedIndexChanged` handler at your ComboBox:

```
private void cmbSize_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    float size = Convert.ToSingle(((ComboBox)sender).Text);

    richTextBox1.Font = new Font(richTextBox1.Font.FontFamily, size);
}
```

This will set the font size of the RichtTextBox (assuming its name is `richTextBox1`)